# How to seperate link to get product info?

Tags: javascript, regex, url

I want to get the product detail from link with javascript.

Product name is always between "item-detail-page-" and "--"
Product price is always between "--" and "-"

Sample links:

```
https://www.blabla.com/products/item-detail-page-proofice-paper--20-14554/1
https://www.blabla.com/products/item-detail-page-faber-pencil--100-145354/2
https://www.blabla.com/products/item-detail-page-led-lamp-xl--55-143555/1
```

I can get the url of page with "var currentLocation = window.location;" But how can I divide the link and get these 2 information?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You need to extract `proofice-paper`, `faber-pencil` and `led-lamp-xl` in the examples provided. Correct? Could you please post the code where exactly you are getting issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the various function of string to achieve it. Please check the below code.

```js
var url1 = 'https://www.blabla.com/products/item-detail-page-proofice-paper--20-14554/1'
var url2 = 'https://www.blabla.com/products/item-detail-page-faber-pencil--100-145354/2'
var url3 = 'https://www.blabla.com/products/item-detail-page-led-lamp-xl--55-143555/1'

function getProductInfo(url) {
    var urlComponent = url.split('/');
    var itemDetsils = urlComponent[urlComponent.length - 2];

    return {
        productName: itemDetsils.substring(17, itemDetsils.indexOf("--")),
        productprice: itemDetsils.substring(itemDetsils.indexOf("--") + 2, itemDetsils.lastIndexOf("-")),
    }
}


console.log(getProductInfo(url1));
console.log(getProductInfo(url2));
console.log(getProductInfo(url3));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const regex = /(?<=item-detail-page-)(.*)(?=--)/g
window.location.pathname.match(regex)
```

should do what you want reliably :)